# CKEditor: toolbar is not Appearing

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I created a plugin named timestamp.
Code for plugin.js is this:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'timestamp',
{
    init: function( editor )
    {
        editor.addCommand( 'insertTimestamp',
            {
                exec : function( editor )
                {    
                    var timestamp = new Date();
                    editor.insertHtml( timestamp.toString() );
                }
            });
        editor.ui.addButton( 'Timestamp',
        {
            label: 'Insert Timestamp',
            command: 'insertTimestamp',
            icon: this.path + '/icons/timestamp.png'
        } );
    }
} );
```

Icon is in `/_source/plugins/timestamp/icons`

But when I tried to add plugin in `./samples/fullpage.html`, even toolbar not appearing
code:

```
<script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
                fullPage: true,
                extraPlugins: 'wysiwygarea,timestamp',
            toolbar :
            [
                [ 'Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList' ],
                [ 'Timestamp' ]
            ]
            });



</script>
```

If i tried to add this plugin in config.js, toolbar appear but without timestamp(my custom plugin)

code:

```
config.extraPlugins ='timestamp';
```

please let me know whats going wrong.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `extraPlugin: 'wysiwygarea'` or `extraPlugins : 'docprops'` is not required in full.html. Hopfully it will work:)

Comment: That won't change anything.

Comment: I was having the same problem but just doing this it works.Custom button appeared:)

Comment: I'm confused :) That looks like a bug. We'll investigate that, because there's nothing wrong in having wysiwygarea in extra plugins.

Comment: I dont know the reason.You better know but code is right there , for no good reason button was not appearing in toolbar.but just doing this it appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Your toolbar stopped appearing after you've added your plugin much probably because you've got some JS error in that plugin which breaks everything. Check your console and paste info here (or try to fix the issue by yourself :)).

Comment: I have checked the console there is no error.but still button not apperaing in toolbar. please anybody help me.i m in great truoble due to this:'(

Comment: Hm... so you'd have to upload somewhere your CKEditor sample on which you work so I can check it. Otherwise I won't be able to guess what's wrong.